# Is it possible for LyX to put space automatically after $ $ environment?

Tags: lyx

When I edit document, I usually don't see if there is space after inline equation or not. I have to compile and look where my text spills with equations.
Is it possible to redefine this environment or do something to make LyX put defaultly a space bar after every $ $?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure you are actually *entering* the space into LyX; as I recall, LyX's math rendering gave some false horizontal space when entering inline math.  Remember that LyX won't let you put two spaces in a row; you can't accidentally over-do it.  (This can be 'solved' in TeX as part of your preamble, but trust me when I say you don't want it.  Consider the phrase 'if you look at the *x*-axis…'—any automatic horizontal space would make it look positively *awful*.)

Comment: I would be even happier if two neighbouring spaces would become one.

Comment: Try putting `n>=2` spaces into LyX and see what happens, paying close attention to the echo area at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using a recent version of LyX (not necessarily the 2.1 beta), because they decreased the space around inline equations a couple of versions ago to help with exactly this problem. Another way to see whether there is a space more clearly in LyX is to turn on instant preview (in preferences, under graphics), which has an even smaller gap around equations. So long as your computer can handle it, this is a pretty good idea anyway.

It might help to know how LyX handles spaces. In text, you cannot type two in a row without forcing one manually by pressing ctrl+space.¹ In math, you cannot even type one space! Pressing the space key in math moves you out of the inset you're currently in. For example, in the equation $x_{\mathrm{foo}}$ with your cursor inside the mathrm box, pressing space once will move you out of it, pressing it a second time will move you out of the subscript, and pressing it a third time will take you out of the math inset entirely. Only pressing space a fourth time will produce a space in the text!

The moral of the story: if your cursor is in a math inset, you can (and should) just repeatedly hit space until you're sure you've produced an actual space in text. You do not need to worry that you might press it too often.

Sorry that this is not exactly a direct answer to your question, but I don't think it would be a great idea anyway. Sometimes you don't want a space after an equation, such as at the end of a sentence ("... and therefore $n=1$.").

(¹ Technically it is possible to enter two spaces in a row in LyX by putting your cursor *before* a space and pressing the space key, but this is just a convenience to help you enter a new word in the middle of text. If you manage to get two spaces then they will still output as one, and will disappear as soon as you move the cursor.)

Comment: Thank you. This is not exactly what I wanted, but this idea with instant preview seems good.